# Newly created local claim isn't shown in claim configuration WSO2 Identity Server when using remote Postgres DB

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to map a newly created local claim to the claims of a service providers.

**Some notes about my WSO2 implementation:**

I am using Postgres databases in AWS's Relational Database Service. I followed the steps here to set up my master, metrics, and bps databases: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Changing+to+PostgreSQL#ChangingtoPostgreSQL-ChangingthedefaultdatabaseChangingthedefaultWSO2_CARBON_DBdatasource

**My steps to map the claim look like this:**

1. Create a local claim
   [image: Create local claim]
2. Attempt to add the newly created claim to a service provider
   [image: Add claim to SP]

My issue is that the claim I created in step 1 doesn't appear in the dropdown in step 2.  I have confirmed that the claim is being written to my master Postgres database under the `idn_claim` table.  If it's in the `idn_claim` table, shouldn't it show in the dropdown when adding a claim?

The same steps have worked for me with the following setups:

1. Using the built-in H2 database (no config changes)
2. Using a LOCAL Postgres database that is setup using the same configuration files and seeding scripts as the scenario above.

I'm stumped about why everything works as expected using the H2 database or a Local Postgres database (with identical setup) but it doesn't work with a Postgres database in AWS.

Comment: Did you check the whole list, without relying on the alphabetical order?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the claim isn't in the list

Comment: Have you changed anything other than the database connection details from the test you did with local Postgres database?

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by wiping my Postgres database and re-setting up the tables.  I'm not sure what the issue was, but it is resolved now.  Thanks for your time.